# Differences in realization of intrusive-r and linking-r?

Tags: english, phonetics, rhoticity

Are there any good papers that have investigated this? I seemed to notice this with some speakers on television that their intrusive-r's seemed less pronounced than their linking-r's.

I did find a research paper comparing intrusive-r's to permanent /r/'s, as in comparing minimal pairs of “saw ice” and “saw rice” and concluding that case there was such a difference that native speakers could reliably tell both apart, but nothing on for instance “sore arm” *vs.* “saw arm” to see whether the linking-r might be realized more pronouncedly than the intrusive-r.

Comment: What's the paper? What difference did it say was responsible for the distinction?

Comment: @Nardog it's here I guess: https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_137983/component/file_1093600/content — the duration of the intrusive-r's are shorter than the persistent-r's which cues native speakers easily, but non-natives not so  much.